# How do I count the number of characters in a long string in TCL?

Tags: string, tcl, space

I tried this, but it doesn't count the spaces.
I need to limit the input text to 255 characters.

`put text_length [string length $additional_information]`

I would like to count the number of entered characters including spaces and enter, and save the number of characters in text_length (with space and enter).

put text_length [string length $additional_information]

Comment: What is this `put` command?

Comment: Pls provide exemplary input data, showing what you are claiming. `string length`  reports whitespace etc.

Comment: put is a set command

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
set additional_information "   abc\n"
set text_length [string length $additional_information]
puts $text_length
if {$text_length > 255} {
    .button configure -state disabled
} else {
    .button configure -state enabled
}
```

This should output 7 and grey out the button.

Comment: THX for your Answer!
That's almost what I need. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. $additional_information stores the entered text (from the user interface -> SpeedMaxx), I want to convert this entered text into numbers so that I know how many characters I have (including spaces and newlines). If this number is more than 255, the Button is grayed out, so the client cannot proceed.

Comment: "the Button is grayed out" -- is this a Tk gui?

Comment: yepp, this is a TK GUI (SpeedMaxx by Acatec)

Comment: @SchelteBron I think the original question was worded badly and asked the number to max out at 255 (which is what the range is for). I didn't have the time to update it until now, though.